# Does the Goblin Shaman's Mask work on Rosie's second form?

Tags: lost-ruins

The description for the Goblin Shaman's Mask says it increases damage to goblins and orcs by 50%. Does this include Rosie's second form during her boss fight when she transforms into a goblin?

[image: Rosie as a goblin]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

This isn't limited to her 2nd form. She always takes additional damage from the shaman's mask.

Weapon used: dagger (Assassin mode criticals). Damage without the mask: 15. Damage with the mask: 23.